# How do I sync my Canon mirrorless camera with a Godox manual AC strobe?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, godox, sync, monolights

I’ve just bought the Godox SK400 II strobe and I have a Canon EOS M50 camera. I bought a cable to connect them but I still can’t seem to sync them? Do you have any tips on how to sync this strobe with a camera?

Comment: You need to tell us what specific kind of cable you have.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to sync with the SK400 II and have the most control would be to get a for-Canon Godox 2.4 GHz radio transmitter unit for your camera hotshoe: e.g., an XPro-C or Flashpoint R2 Pro II-C, or TT685-C. The SK400 II has a built-in radio receiver in the Godox system, so a Godox transmitter on your camera could remotely fire, adjust the power, and control the modeling light on the strobe.

Using a TTL sync cable is not possible, since the SK400 II does not have a flash foot to attach it to. Any other sync cable would require a 3.5mm connector for the SK400 II, and a PC (Prontor-Compur) or 3.5mm connector *and* a hotshoe-to-PC (or 3.5mm) adapter for the M50, since it does not have a flash sync port of any kind built in. And a PC/3.5mm sync cable would be a manual-only connection that could only allow the camera to fire the strobe. All other settings would have to be adjusted on the strobe itself.

You *could*, however, also use the pop-up flash on the M50 to remotely fire the SK400 II, since it also has the S1/S2 optical slave modes. If your pop-up flash is in M, use S1; if your pop-up is in TTL, use S2, so that the metering pre-flash is skipped and won't trip the strobe too early.  This is also manual-only but wouldn't require you to purchase any additional gear.

Comment: Another option is a Godox flash such as the tt350c or tt685c as a wireless controller. This also provides additional lighting options.